# Vercel dynamic build command based on stage

Tags: expo, vercel

I have an Expo app where the web component is hosted through Vercel. I use the Vercel GitHub integration for automatic deployment. Expo has a different build command for staging builds and production builds, and it doesn't appear Vercel supports environment/staging based build commands. I'm wondering if I'm possibly missing something and this is possible or anyone has another way of handling this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was in a similar situation and managed to solve it with a shell script.

Here is an example you can try out:

```
#!/bin/bash
 
if [[ $VERCEL_ENV == "production"  ]] ; 
then 
  echo "Building production"
  yarn build:production
else 
  echo "Building staging"
  yarn build:staging
fi
```

And lets say you called the file `vercel.sh`, you would configure vercel [buildCommand](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/deployments/configure-a-build#build-command) to be `sh vercel.sh`.

Basically, from the shell script you'll be able to use any of the [system environment variables](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/projects/environment-variables#system-environment-variables) vercel provides.

Comment: Thank you @Janko, I actually emailed Vercel and they essentially suggested the same thing. :)